# how to append default dropdown option value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to append option `value=0` in my dropdown list.  Here is my code:

```
for (i = 1; i < = wardcount; i++) {
    var option = $('<option/>');
    option.attr({
        'value': i
    }).text(i);

    $('#ward_no').append(option);
}
```

Comment: Start the loop from `i = 0`

Comment: no i should be 1.I want to append <option value=0>select</option> in my dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider it as text.

```
let zero  =`<option value="0">Select</option>`
$('#ward_no').append(zero);
for (i = 1; i <= wardcount; i++) {
    let option = `<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`
    $('#ward_no').append(option);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- for (i = 1; i <= wardcount; i++)
+ for (i = 0; i < wardcount; i++)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do it before the loop.

```
$("#ward_no").empty();
$("#ward_no").append($("<option>", {value: 1, text: "select"}));
for (i = 1; i < = wardcount; i++) {
    var option = $('<option/>', {value: i, text: i});
    $('#ward_no').append(option);
}
```

Comment: when i use $('#ward_no').html(""); this before loop default option is missing.but i want empty the dropdown before choose another option

Comment: You do this after you empty the dropdown and before you add all the numbered options.